# Authenticity Token in Grails

Tags: security, authentication, grails

Is there a way to implement an authenticity token within Grails? I saw some nice implementations in Rails and Play([Security CSRF in Play](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/security#csrf)). Is there something equal to Grails? I want to use this to keep my REST interface valid.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails has something similar.  Add the `useToken` attribute on your `g:form` tags and wrap your controller methods in `withToken {}` closures.  There's more information in the [Grails manual](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.11%20Handling%20Duplicate%20Form%20Submissions).

Comment: Yes I know this solution but I am having a REST Json Service which dont uses forms at all. Is there another possibilty to use this token with such web services?

Comment: I'm don't think REST clients would be susceptible to CSRF exploits.  However, you can use `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SynchronizerToken` to store a token in the session in the same way a `g:form` does.  Take a look at the source for `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.FormTagLib` to see how grails does it.

Comment: @ataylor This is a related question you might know the answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715903/csrf-protection-for-rest-calls-in-grails-with-security-token